# php: how to change instance $this in the class?

Tags: php

index.php

```
<?
require("sql.php");
require("Annonce.php");

$annonces = new Annonce();
$annonces = $annonces->getAll();
print_r($annonces);

?>
```

Annonce.php

```
<?php     
require("DB.php");
class Annonce extends DB {      
    function __construct() {    
    }
}   
 ?>
```

DB.php

```
<?php     
    class DB {
        public static $debug = true;       

        function __construct() {
            echo "construction";        
        }        
        function debugtxt($sql) {
            if ($this::$debug) echo "$sql<br>";
        }
        function delete() {
            $id = $this->id;
            $table = get_class($this);
            $sql="delete from $table where id=$id";
            $this->debugtxt($sql);
            $GLOBALS["db"]->exec($sql);
        }              
        function getAll() {
            $table = get_class($this);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table";
            $stmt = $GLOBALS["db"]->query($sql);
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->debugtxt($sql);
            return $results;
        }                      
        function create() {
            $table = get_class($this);              
            $keys = array_keys((array)$this);
            $keys = "`".implode("`,`", $keys)."`";        
            $values = array_values((array)$this);
            $values = "'".implode("','", $values)."'";        
            $sql="insert into $table($keys) values($values)";
            $this->debugtxt($sql);
            $GLOBALS["db"]->exec($sql);
            $this->debugtxt($sql);        
        }        
    }
     ?>
```

Ok that's pretty cool: I can for instance to

```
$annonce = new Annonce();
$annonce->id =1;
$annonce->delete();
```

But to retrieve annonces I need to do:

```
$annonce = new Annonce();
$annonce = $annonce->getAll();
```

Which is not very good: is there a way to do :

```
$annonce->getAll()
```

so the getAll function changes the instance that called him ?

Comment: I don't get it ... What's your problem (French:  C'est quoi ton problème ?)

Comment: You can make the method `static`. But there is still a lot to do in order to refine your class, e.g. the global db, the fact that the class should not be aware of the persisting layer [in this case MySQL]...and so on.

Comment: Plutot que de faire $annonce = $annonce->getAll();
je voudrais faire $annonce->getAll() ! Donc getAll doit modifier l'objet qui l'appelle.

Comment: In this case, in getAll method, you have to set annonces, 
`$this->annonces = $results`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static function, but you have to rewrite your class.

You can try something like

```
<?php
class Annonce extends DB
{
    public static function getAll()
    {
        # Get all annonces
    }

    public static function delete($id)
    {
        # Delete annonce with ID
    }

    // ... 
}
```

And then you can retrive your annonces using

```
Annonce::getAll();
```

Also you can delete using

```
Annonce::delete($id)
```

Attention:  using static methods, you cannot use $this